# undefined reference error while linking static library in bitbake recipe

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm new to yocto and bitbake and I'm building a voip application for a custom imx6 board. I want to use pjsip libraries to build my application, I have compiled pjsip in my yocto build and generated pjsip libraries ( all pjsip libraries are static). I'm having issues building a recipe for my application that calls the pjsip functions. Below is how my recipe looks

Filename: rttapp.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple voip application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM ="file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PR = "r1"

SRC_URI += "file://rttapp.c"
SRC_URI += "file://include"
SRC_URI += "file://lib"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

CFLAGS_prepend += "-I${WORKDIR}/include -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 ->DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1"
LDFLAGS_append += "-L${WORKDIR}/lib -lpjsua2-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi -lstdc++ ->lpjsua-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi -lm -lrt -lpthread -lasound"

do_compile() {
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} rttapp.c -o rttapp
}
```

When i do bitbake rttapp, the error i see is as below:

```
/usr/src/debug/rttapp/1.0-r1/rttapp.c:159: undefined reference to pjsua_create'. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please advise

Comment: Are you sure that you should link to libstd++.so using a C compiler? Also, your not stating which version and doc layers you're using.

Comment: Agreed thanks for pointing it out, removed libstd++,  but the primary error still remains...did not expect this change to fix it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue, it was actually a silly mistake

```
${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} rttapp.c -o rttapp
```

should have been

```
${CC} rttapp.c ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o rttapp
```

Comment: Any reason for this ? I'd never have guessed that as a solution, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As your recipe depends on `pjsip`, you need to have an explicit dependency. Just add

```
DEPENDS += 'pjsip'
```

to your recipe.

As of the `Pyro` release, no global sysroot is being used. Rather, all recipe has to explicitly add all their own dependencies.

Comment: I still see the same error, adding DEPENDS made not difference

Comment: Well, in such case, verify that the `pjsip` recipe actually install the static libraries and the name of those libraries.

Comment: Probably this is where I'm missing something and would really appreciate your help my pjsip recipe, builds and installs the .a files into ${WORKDIR}/build directory and I manually copied them into files directory in the rttapp directory

Comment: Let the pjsip recipe install the header files and libraries into `${D}` add usual. When your recipe then depends on pjsip, the libraries and header files should be installed into the sysroot (either the global one, or for Pyro and later, into the recipe specific sysroot).

Comment: Since they are all static libraries I dont want to install them into {D}, as I dont want them to a part of my image. I just need to build my executable by linking it to them. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Install them into `${D}` anyway. They won't be part of the image (pretty default), as they'll be put into a `pjsip-staticdev` package. No recipe is allowed to touch any other recipes `${WORKDIR}`.